# Windows commands not working

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-server-2003

I have tried to run several different windows commands and most of them return an error message. i first ran `taskkill`, then `tasklist`, and then `systeminfo` and none seemed to work.

```
C:\>tasklist
ERROR: The specified module could not be found.
```

I tried running command prompt as administrator and i tried using the full location `c:\windows\system32\tasklist` and all return the same error `The specified module could not be found.` I navigated to the system32 folder and was able to locate the exe. this commands exists and when i run HELP from command prompt it gives the command and its short description. but trying to run them returns an error message. i looked around online and couldn't seem to find anything specifically identifying a solution to this problem.

operating system is windows 2003

Comment: What version of windows? You may also want to update the question with the value of your PATH environment variable the you see in the actual console where you have the issue.

Comment: windows server 2003

Comment: What is the value of the PATH variable?

Comment: %systemroot%\system32

Comment: That is the only thing in PATH? I would think that you would have more issues than this then. Also, are you getting the PATH variable in the actual console? Or are you looking at it in machine properties? Also, what is the value of SYSTEMROOT?

Comment: cd to `c:\windows\system32` from command line.  Then try to run `tasklist.exe` and see what happens.

Comment: i got it from the machine properties. theres alot more in path, but that is the path to the commands im trying to run. the path variable is exactly as it was last week and the week before that, etc. while this problem began today. system root is C:\WINDOWS

Comment: tried cd to c:\windows\system32. still gives the same error. i can navigate to the exe from windows explorer so i know the module can be found, but for some reason it isnt being recognized or executed.

Comment: Don't know if this is an option for you or not but you can try booting to the OS installation media and running a repair install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the registry value:

`hklm/software/microsoft/windows nt/winlogon/sfcdisable`

to **4** from **0** and run `sfc /scannow` and the problem should be fixed.

Comment: You mean "hklm\software\microsoft\windows nt\currentversion\winlogon\sfcdisable"

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like some Windows DLLs are corrupted. Try running system file checker (sfc.exe) and see whether it finds anything missing. Also might be caused by some viruses or malware.

Comment: i will run sfc and see if this solves the problem. this past weekend ran some virus scans and malwarebytes and removed alot of hazardous stuff from the system. restarted last night and now this morning this problem exists. could be related.

Comment: ran sfc and still having the problem